# Record id is showing null

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" access="global" />
```

---

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {           

        var recordId= component.get('v.recordId');
        console.log('recordId--'+recordId);


        var action = component.get('c.forCheckingActivate');
        action.setParams({
            "recordId":recordId
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

```
    global with sharing class  Activate_Deactivate_Controller {


         @AuraEnabled
         public static String forCheckingActivate( String recId){
          system.debug('hello');   
          system.debug('recId'+recId);   

             return 'objectAPIName'; 

    }
}
```

Comment: mind sharing where exatly you are using this component? is in on a record detail page? in LEX, communities?

Comment: In record page of the object

Comment: Can you share the minimal reproducible code for your component? What are the interfaces you have on your component, viz., force:hasRecordId, etc.? How are you receiving the id on your component. These details will help anyone here to be able to help you. Also can you make sure your code above reflects exactly how it is, as you mentioned that there’s no issue with the parameter name here.

Comment: <aura:component controller="Activate_Deactivate_Controller" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global">

Comment: I have to get the field values using Sobjectname.How can I get that.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have implemented `force:hasRecordId` in your component markup.

Your apex method is asking for `recId` as input parameter but you are passing `recordId` for parameter name in ControllerJS.

Try this:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {           

        var recordId= component.get('v.recordId');
        console.log('recordId--'+recordId);


        var action = component.get('c.forCheckingActivate');
        action.setParams({
            "recId":recordId
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: I have used force:hasRecordId in my component markup and used recId as parameter but still recordId is null in apex class.

Comment: Care to post a screenshot of your browser logs and relevant dump from debug logs? Interested in seeing what is printing and what is not.

Comment: Is this resolved I am also getting same issue